# protools workspace window freez and crashes .

Tags: pro-tools, workspace

Hi
I'm using pt 9.0.2 LE on a win 7 system. works just great! 
just recently when ever i open the workspace for searching sounds on my drives, it freez and make me restart the whole system.

any ideas?..  i'v searched the net with no results.

Thanks

N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I posted this for someone else recently that was dealing with a bit of a corrupt session file and 99% of the time this will resolve your issues I'll re-post it again here (this time Win7 specific. What you should do first thing is delete your databases and preferences.

Not an issue with you, but I'm going to see if I can make a community wiki with all this info since this and similar problems pop up all the time and since this is typically the best way to fix them and since Avid has their own user forum and tech database that has all this info; it seems silly to clog this place up with a bunch of Pro Tools problem threads.

---

Here's a list of Troubleshooting tips and Optimizations for Windows 7 from Avid:

http://avid.custkb.com/avid/app/selfservice/search.jsp?DocId=349411

**Go to the section for "Delete Digidesign Databases and Preferences"*

---

**Taken from the link above*

Delete Digidesign Databases and Preferences

To delete Digidesign Database folders for all hard drives in Windows 7:

```
Go to your Start menu and click on Computer.
Double-click on the C: drive.
Double-click on Program Files.
Go to the Digidesign folder.
Go to the Pro Tools folder.
Right-click on the Databases folder and delete it.
NOTE: If you are using Pro Tools HD, DV Toolkit 2 or Complete Production Toolkit, you will want to backup your Catalogs folder before deleting the Databases folder.
```

To delete Pro Tools preference files in Windows 7:

```
Go to your Start menu and click on Computer.
Double-click on the C: drive.
Double-click on Program Files.
Go to the Common Files folder.
Go to the Digidesign folder.
Go to the DAE folder.
Right-click on the DAE Prefs folder and delete it.
Go back to your C: drive.
Double-click on Users.
Double-click on your user name.
Go to the AppData folder.
NOTE: If the Appdata is not showing, click on Organize and choose 'Folder and Search Options'.
Click on the View tab.
Select 'Show Hidden Files and Folders'.
Click Apply and OK. AppData should now be viewable.
Go to the Roaming folder.
Right-click on the Digidesign folder and delete it.
```

Comment: @Nimi - Don't sweat it. It's no big deal. We all know how bad tech issues suck, especially if the answer is hard to find.

Comment: Thanks again @Syndicate Synthetique - for your time.
Though i got to say deleting pref and db didnt solve my issue.
PT still get freez and stuck to restart after searching files in the workspace window.

n.

Comment: @Nimi - I'm seeing all over the place that people are having this same problem (on both operating systems) and no answers have been posted. Must be a bug with this newest version. When my tech friend from Avid gets into work on Monday I'll ask him what's up.

Comment: @Syndicate Synthetique - Thanks ! i'll really appreciate it.
b.t.w , its happening also after i'v upgrd to the new PT9.0.3 update.
n.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, this totally slipped my mind. I don't see him online right now. It's kinda rare, he only logs into chat for about 30m every couple days or so, hopefully I won't forget again.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild your databases for each drive?

Unmount all drives and only add the ones you need (system hard drive) and see if it still gives you the problem. If it works, then isolate what drive is giving you trouble, copy off the files you need and reformat it and see if that works.

That's all I got. Hope it helps! Good luck!